# Facebook iOS SDK and swift: how get user's profile picture

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

i have integrated Facebook sdk in Xcode 6 (with swift).
During the login i request the public_profile permission:

```
FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: {
...
...
```

So i request the user's information:

```
FBRequestConnection.startForMeWithCompletionHandler { (connection, user, error) -> Void in
...
...
```

Why the user object doesn't contain the profile picture? How can i get the user profile picture? It's not part of the public_profile?

I get the following information:

```
2015-01-25 01:25:18.858 Test[767:23804] {
"first_name" = xxx;
gender = xxx;
id = xxxxxxxxx;
"last_name" = xxxxxx;
link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxxxxx/";
locale = "xxxxx";
name = "xxxxxxx xxxxxxx";
timezone = 1;
"updated_time" = "2013-12-21T18:45:29+0000";
verified = 1;
}
```

P.S: xxx for privacy

Comment: For xcode 8.3.3 and swift-4(beta) use :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45462114/1168602

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The profile picture is in fact public and you can simply by adding the user id to Facebook's designated profile picture url address, ex:

```
var userID = user["id"] as NSString     
var facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large"
```

This particular url address should return the "large" version of the user's profile picture, but several more photo options are available [in the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/picture).

Comment: Hi. Some months late but, may I ask... where in the docs are those photo options available? I can't seem to find them on Graph API 2.4: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/picture

Comment: @AlejandroIván The doc page I linked to now says "This document refers to an outdated version of Graph API. Please use the latest version. Graph API Version v2.2", so perhaps those photo options are no longer available in 2.4.

Comment: That's what I thought. Surprisingly, even if not documented "officially", using `type=large` or another ones (I'm using `width=150&height=150`) seem to work just fine. Thank you!

Comment: This answer pointed me in the right direction. So, to complete my function I added this:
 if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: facebookProfileUrl!) {
            imageProfile.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
Thanks @LyndseyScott

Comment: Thanks @LyndseyScott - for people using this in the future, don't forget to use 'https' instead of 'http' to silence the Apple Security complaints :)

Comment: simple and sweet

Answer (score 53):

If you want to get the picture in the same request as the rest of the users information you can do it all in one graph request. It's a little messy but it beats making another request.

A more **Swift 3** approach

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, picture.type(large)"])
let _ = request?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
    guard let userInfo = result as? [String: Any] else { return } //handle the error

    //The url is nested 3 layers deep into the result so it's pretty messy
    if let imageURL = ((userInfo["picture"] as? [String: Any])?["data"] as? [String: Any])?["url"] as? String {
        //Download image from imageURL
    }
})
```

**Swift 2**

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, picture.type(large)"])
request.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) in
    let info = result as! NSDictionary
    if let imageURL = info.valueForKey("picture")?.valueForKey("data")?.valueForKey("url") as? String {
        //Download image from imageURL
    }
})
```

Answer (score 25):

With Facebook SDK 4.0, you can use:

**Swift:**

```
    let pictureRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture?type=large&redirect=false", parameters: nil)
    pictureRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({
        (connection, result, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("\(result)")
        } else {
            println("\(error)")
        }
    })
```

**Objective-C:**

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/picture?type=large&redirect=false"]
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
    if (!error){
       NSLog(@"result: %@",result);}
    else {
       NSLog(@"result: %@",[error description]);
     }}];
```

Comment: this pointed me in the right direction for getting other user info things, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314124/get-email-and-name-facebook-sdk-v4-4-0-swift

Comment: id/picture?type=normal&redirect=false worked great for me, thank you. redirect=false did wonders

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 4 approach :-**

```
private func fetchUserData() {
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, email, name, picture.width(480).height(480)"])
    graphRequest?.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error",error!.localizedDescription)

        }
        else{
            print(result!)
            let field = result! as? [String:Any]
            self.userNameLabel.text = field!["name"] as? String
            if let imageURL = ((field!["picture"] as? [String: Any])?["data"] as? [String: Any])?["url"] as? String {
                print(imageURL)
                let url = URL(string: imageURL)
                let data = NSData(contentsOf: url!)
                let image = UIImage(data: data! as Data)
                self.profileImageView.image = image
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: your if-else statement is wrong. It should be if error == nil and you should change the codes as well.

Comment: @emresancaktar Its correct . if error != nil than it will print error.

Answer (score 7):

if you want get bigger picture , just replace "type = large" to width=XX&height=XX

but the biggest picture you can get is original picture

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] 
                              initWithGraphPath:@"me/picture?width=1080&height=1080&redirect=false" 
                              parameters:nil 
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"]; 

[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(
                            FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                            id result, 
                            NSError *error) { 
if (!error) 
{ 
   NSLog(@"result = %@",result);
   NSDictionary *dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result; 
   NSDictionary *data = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"]; 
   NSString *photoUrl = (NSString *)[data objectForKey:@"url"]; 
} 
else 
{ 
   NSLog(@"result = %@",[error description]); } 
}];
```

Answer (score 4):

@Brandon Gao solution gave me a 200X200 thumbnail...
To get a bigger size I used `FBSDKProfile` to get a path with size, that is also more modular and not hard-coded (although I did have to type in the *graph.facebook.com* part...)

```
let size = CGSize(width: 1080, height: 1080)
let path = FBSDKProfile.currentProfile().imagePathForPictureMode(.Normal, size: size)
let url = "https://graph.facebook.com/\(path)"
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL).response { 
    (request, response, data, error) -> Void in
    if  let imageData = data as? NSData,
        let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {
            self.buttonImage.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

Somehow I didn't get a 1080X1080 image though, FB gave me a 1117X1117... :\

Comment: nice solution, but I needed to load the profile first:
`FBSDKProfile.loadCurrentProfileWithCompletion`

Answer (score 4):

For swift this is the simple way for get the url of the photo with and specific size:

```
    let params: [NSObject : AnyObject] = ["redirect": false, "height": 800, "width": 800, "type": "large"]
    let pictureRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture", parameters: params, HTTPMethod: "GET")
    pictureRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({
        (connection, result, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("\(result)")


           let dictionary = result as? NSDictionary
           let data = dictionary?.objectForKey("data")
           let urlPic = (data?.objectForKey("url"))! as! String
           print(urlPic)



        } else {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    })

}
```

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift 5**

First add the fields  that you need

```
let params = ["fields": "first_name, last_name, email, picture"]
```

Create the graph request

```
let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params, tokenString: token.tokenString, version: nil, httpMethod: .get)
graphRequest.start { (connection, result, error) in }
```

You will get the result in json

```
{
  "first_name": "",
  "last_name": "",
  "picture": {
    "data": {
      "height": 50,
      "is_silhouette": false,
      "url": "",
      "width": 50
    }
  },
  "id": ""
}
```

According to the json response, catch the result

```
if let error = error {
            print("Facebook graph request error: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Facebook graph request successful!")
            guard let json = result as? NSDictionary else { return }
            if let id = json["id"] as? String {
                print("\(id)")
            }
            if let email = json["email"] as? String {
                print("\(email)")
            }
            if let firstName = json["first_name"] as? String {
                print("\(firstName)")
            }
            if let lastName = json["last_name"] as? String {
                print("\(lastName)")
            }
            if let profilePicObj = json["picture"] as? [String:Any] {
                if let profilePicData = profilePicObj["data"] as? [String:Any] {
                    print("\(profilePicData)")
                    if let profilePic = profilePicData["url"] as? String {
                        print("\(profilePic)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You can also get custom width profile image by sending the required width in the params

```
let params = ["fields": "first_name, last_name, email, picture.width(480)"]
```

This is how the whole code would like

```
if let token = AccessToken.current {
            let params = ["fields": "first_name, last_name, email, picture.width(480)"]
            let graphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: params,
                                            tokenString: token.tokenString, version: nil, httpMethod: .get)
            graphRequest.start { (connection, result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Facebook graph request error: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("Facebook graph request successful!")
                    guard let json = result as? NSDictionary else { return }
                    if let id = json["id"] as? String {
                        print("\(id)")
                    }
                    if let email = json["email"] as? String {
                        print("\(email)")
                    }
                    if let firstName = json["first_name"] as? String {
                        print("\(firstName)")
                    }
                    if let lastName = json["last_name"] as? String {
                        print("\(lastName)")
                    }
                    if let profilePicObj = json["picture"] as? [String:Any] {
                        if let profilePicData = profilePicObj["data"] as? [String:Any] {
                            print("\(profilePicData)")
                            if let profilePic = profilePicData["url"] as? String {
                                print("\(profilePic)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Check out Graph API Explorer for more fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code For Swift 3.0 to get the user information

```
  func getFbId(){
if(FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil){
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id,name , first_name, last_name , email,picture.type(large)"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
    guard let Info = result as? [String: Any] else { return } 


    if let imageURL = ((Info["picture"] as? [String: Any])?["data"] as? [String: Any])?["url"] as? String {
        //Download image from imageURL
    }
if(error == nil){
print("result")
}
})
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Lyndsey Scott.
For Kingfisher, please add enable request http to .plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>http://graph.facebook.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Then set your user's picture profile to ImageView.

```
let facebookId = "xxxxxxx"
let facebookProfile: String = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(facebookId)/picture?type=large"
let url: URL = URL(string: facebookProfile)!
myImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
```